# 504 ERROR while run Order api in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I am trying to run order api for magento 2.3.4,

```
https://xysab.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=abc@gmail.com
```

and getting the error like

```
504 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
 CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt 
failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or 
website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again 
later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot 
and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: wCtuNfGJa7CtoBPQl844VVc-Gl1IDmiHvUlLKb7l213yV9z9q9fGjw==
```

How to fix this?